# UDP socket (multicast) not receiving data (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up a little test application on Linux (Ubuntu) based on some code I wrote (and that worked) for Winsock. As it stands now, it's just a little test that creates a socket (and seemingly successfully connects) only to hang eternally on recv() instead of receiving datagrams. It's a plain blocking socket.

Here's how I create it:

http://pastebin.com/kcCbgxbB

A few further things tested:
- Port is open.
- Other applications are able to receive data from the multicast address successfully.

So clearly I'm overlooking something. Help greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: You aren't checking all of your calls to setsockopt() to see if they succeeded or not.  Perhaps one of them is failing, and that is related to your problem?

Comment: Good point, I was taking their success for granted more or less :) However, added checks show they also succeed properly.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine..

Comment: Thanks for that. Reaffirms my conviction it's a config. issue.

Comment: For some reason, it did not work here with Mac and Ubuntu, but worked in both when I bound to INADDR_ANY instead of binding to specific interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, in the end a little system configuration and bugfixing went a long way:

a) As root, I'd had to do the following to disable the reverse packet filter:
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
+ The same for ethX.

b) Add a bogus route for the ethX (route add -net 224.0.0.0. netmask 224.0.0.0 ethX)

c) Bind the socket to the to-be-joined group's IP (otherwise any subsequent socket would get all packets from all groups I joined on that particular port).

d) Set the interface member of the ip_mreq struct to the IP of the adapter we're receiving on.

And then all was fine and dandy, test runs fast & smooth (pulling 125 multicast transport streams @ around 800-900 mbit - sure this can be smarter, but still). Thanks for all the pointers.

Answer (score 5):

In Unix systems, when using a socket for multicast you should bind to INADDR_ANY, not to a interface.

Multicast filtering by interface (i.e. not receive mcast from other interfaces than the specified one) is already in place because you are correctly filling imr_interface.

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'filtering' exactly. `imr_interface` chooses the interface via which the IGMP JOIN is sent: in other words, which subnet is aware of your membership. If you let it default, you let the static IP routing tables decide, which in most cases is correct. In a multi-homed host it may be necessary to issue a join per interface.

Comment: In all cases the eventual software will be used on multihomed systems. That said, on Winsock INADDR_ANY indeed works fine. When binding the socket to ANY and the interface to a specific NICs IP however the group join always fails. -- But yes, I'll revert to INADDR_ANY for now.